# shell script to moving files from one server to another server using sftp

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jar

Here I am moving jars from  server  A to server B using sftp:

```
[mars@server33 ND_Jars]$ ls
   abc-5.5.0.jar     
   abc1-5.4.3.jar    
   abc2-5.5.0.jar   
   abc3-5.5.0.jar   
   abc4-com-5.5.0.jar

[mars@server33 ND_Jars]$ ll    
total 3552    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mars mars 1184548 Jan  7 14:32 abc1-com-5.5.0.jar     
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mars mars 1130509 Dec 26 11:30 abc2-5.4.3.jar    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mars mars   24694 Dec 30 17:27 abc3-5.5.0.jar    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mars mars   45454 Dec 18 16:25 abc4-5.5.0.jar    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mars mars 1236350 Jan  7 14:32 abc-5.5.0.jar    
[mars@server33 ND_Jars]$ sftp sftpuser@5     
Connecting to 10.0.14.19...     
sftpuser@10.0.14.19's password:    
sftp> cd sftp_dir     
sftp> put abc-5.5.0.jar    
Uploading abc-5.5.0.jar to /sftp_dir/abc-5.5.0.jar
```

I want a shell script so that I can execute all these commands at a go, but I don't know how to hardcode (`sftpuser@10.0.15.19`  and password ) in shell script.

The shell script which I wrote now is:

```
for f in *.jar
do  
    cp -v "$f" /home/webapps/project1/folder2/"${f%.jar}"$(date +%m%d%y).jar  
done
```

Inside these script, I'm just copying the files to another location.

I need a shell script to do `mv` the jars from one server to another server
like the `sftp` command mentioned above.

Comment: use sshpass to supply the script with the password.

Comment: and use ``scp *.jar user@remote` to copy multiple files from one command. AND, Not really a programming Q. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`scp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp).

```
for f in *.jar
do  scp "$f" sftpuser@10.0.14.19:/home/webapps/project1/folder2/"${f%.jar}"$(date +%m%d%y).jar  
done
```

If possible, set up a public key so that no password is required in your script. Good transfer systems like `scp` and `sftp` will be much easier to automate that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `expect` utility installed in your server, you could use it below way:

```
expect <<EOF
set timeout -1
spawn /usr/bin/sftp ${user_name}@${HOSTNAME}
expect "password:"
send "${passwd}\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /the_path/to_put_files/\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "mput *\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOF
```

---

```
set timeout -1 == for sending n number of files to remote server without timeout constraint.
```

Hope this helps.